# ObjectSave causes java.io.UTFDataFormatException

Tags: java-io, railo, cfml

**Raised as bug with Railo https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-2698 - this question should be closed**

I am currently attempting to ObjectSave() on a rather complex Struct which contains instances of some CFCs among other data using the following cfscript (this is a test script I put together to reproduce the issue)

```
<cfscript>
    thisState = session.objBasket.getState();
    writedump(thisState); // dumps the object successfully
    ObjectSave(thisState); // causes java.io.UTFDataFormatException
</cfscript>
```

I am getting the following error `java.io.UTFDataFormatException` (stack trace follows).  Does anyone know of a way to fix this, or is it a matter of simply trying to use the wrong tool for the job?

**Railo versions the error occurs on**

- Railo 4.1.1.009 final (Java 1.7.0_45)
- Railo 4.1.1.009 final (Java 1.7.0_17)
- Railo 4.1.2.001 final (Java 1.7.0_45) (Preview release)

**Railo versions the error does not occur on**

- Railo 4.0.4.001 final (Java 1.7.0_45)

**Stack trace of the error**

> java.io.UTFDataFormatException at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeUTF(ObjectOutputStream.java:2163):2163
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeUTF(ObjectOutputStream.java:2006):2006
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeUTF(ObjectOutputStream.java:868):868
>   at
>   railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.writeExternal(ComponentImpl.java:1975):1975
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1458):1458
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429):1429
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177):1177
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347):347
>   at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1133):1133 at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source):-1 at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43):43
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606):606 at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988):988
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495):1495
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431):1431
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177):1177
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347):347
>   at
>   railo.commons.collection.AbstractMapPro.writeExternal(AbstractMapPro.java:49):49
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1458):1458
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429):1429
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177):1177
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547):1547
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508):1508
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431):1431
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177):1177
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347):347
>   at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1133):1133 at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source):-1 at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43):43
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606):606 at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988):988
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495):1495
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431):1431
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177):1177
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347):347
>   at
>   railo.commons.collection.AbstractMapPro.writeExternal(AbstractMapPro.java:49):49
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1458):1458
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429):1429
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177):1177
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547):1547
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508):1508
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431):1431
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177):1177
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347):347
>   at
>   railo.runtime.converter.JavaConverter.serialize(JavaConverter.java:67):67
>   at
>   railo.runtime.functions.other.ObjectSave.call(ObjectSave.java:31):31
>   at
>   railo.runtime.functions.other.ObjectSave.call(ObjectSave.java:22):22
>   at
>   mso.clientobject_cfc$cf._3(/var/www/html/www/www.simon.test/mso/ClientObject.cfc:476):476
>   at
>   mso.clientobject_cfc$cf.udfCall(/var/www/html/www/www.simon.test/mso/ClientObject.cfc):-1
>   at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:94):94 at
>   railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:307):307 at
>   railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:198):198
>   at
>   railo.runtime.type.scope.UndefinedImpl.callWithNamedValues(UndefinedImpl.java:709):709
>   at
>   railo.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:738):738
>   at
>   railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1513):1513
>   at
>   mso.clientobject_cfc$cf._3(/var/www/html/www/www.simon.test/mso/ClientObject.cfc:437):437
>   at
>   mso.clientobject_cfc$cf.udfCall(/var/www/html/www/www.simon.test/mso/ClientObject.cfc):-1
>   at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:94):94 at
>   railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:307):307 at
>   railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:198):198
>   at railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:617):617 at
>   railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:499):499 at
>   railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1732):1732
>   at
>   railo.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:738):738
>   at
>   railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1513):1513
>   at
>   mso.proxyclientobject_cfm$cf._1(/var/www/html/www/www.simon.test/mso/proxyClientObject.cfm:19):19
>   at
>   mso.proxyclientobject_cfm$cf.udfCall(/var/www/html/www/www.simon.test/mso/proxyClientObject.cfm):-1
>   at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:94):94 at
>   railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:307):307 at
>   railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:211):211 at
>   railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:616):616 at
>   railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:499):499 at
>   railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1715):1715 at
>   railo.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:712):712
>   at
>   railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1503):1503
>   at
>   preparecosting_cfm$cf.call(/var/www/html/www/www.simon.test/prepareCosting.cfm:24):24
>   at
>   railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:834):834
>   at
>   railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:781):781
>   at
>   application_cfc$cf._1(/var/www/html/www/www.simon.test/Application.cfc:177):177
>   at
>   application_cfc$cf.udfCall(/var/www/html/www/www.simon.test/Application.cfc):-1
>   at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:94):94 at
>   railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:307):307 at
>   railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:211):211 at
>   railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:616):616 at
>   railo.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:499):499 at
>   railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1715):1715 at
>   railo.runtime.listener.ModernAppListener.call(ModernAppListener.java:388):388
>   at
>   railo.runtime.listener.ModernAppListener._onRequest(ModernAppListener.java:204):204
>   at
>   railo.runtime.listener.MixedAppListener.onRequest(MixedAppListener.java:18):18
>   at
>   railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.execute(PageContextImpl.java:2167):2167
>   at
>   railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.execute(PageContextImpl.java:2134):2134
>   at
>   railo.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.serviceCFML(CFMLEngineImpl.java:335):335
>   at railo.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet.service(CFMLServlet.java:29):29 at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728):728 at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305):305
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210):210
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222):222
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123):123
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472):472
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171):171
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99):99
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118):118
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407):407
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200):200
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589):589
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310):310
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145):1145
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615):615
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744):744

**Unit test + accompanying cfc that can be used to reproduce**

*javaErrorTest.cfc* (Unit test)

```
component extends='mxunit.framework.TestCase' {
    public void function trySavingLargeNestedStruct() {
        // Prove that it doesn't happen with nested structures
        var nestedStruct = {};
        var nestInMe = nestedStruct;
        // Make a big struct
        var nestedStruct = {};
        var v = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
        for (var i in v) {
            for (var j in v) {
                for (var k in v) {
                    for (var l in v) {
                        nestedStruct[i][j][k][l] = {};
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        debug('Nested struct len = '&len(serialize(nestedStruct)));
        ObjectSave(nestedStruct);
        debug('Nested struct saved without error');
    }
    public void function triggerUTFDataFormatException() {
        // Prove that it happens with objects nested deeply
        var previousLength = 0;
        for (var i=600;i<700;i++) {
            objTest = new TestObject( levels = i );
            var strSerialized = serialize(objTest);
            try {
                ObjectSave(objTest);
            } catch (java.io.UTFDataFormatException e) {
                // Expected place of java.io.UTFDataFormatException
                debug('Levels = '&i-1&' has serialize() length = '&previousLength);
                debug('Levels = '&i&' has serialize() length = '&Len(strSerialized));
                debug(strSerialized);
                debug(e);
                fail('java.io.UTFDataFormatException (expected) error thrown');
            } catch (any e) {
                debug(e);
                fail('Error thrown, not not the expected one');
            }   
            previousLength = Len(strSerialized);
        }
    }
}
```

*TestObject.cfc* (Used within the failing test)

```
component {
    public TestObject function init(
        required numeric levels = 0
    ) {
        variables.a = (arguments.levels > 0)?new TestObject( levels = arguments.levels - 1 ):{};
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you've got a reproducible test case that doesn't occur on previous versions, go ahead and raise it at http://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO

Comment: Hi @PeterBoughton - currently working on that, at present trying to reproduce reliably doesn't seem possible without uploading a lot of source code.  Simpler examples just don't seem to produce the error - starting to wonder if there's a cyclic reference which the fix for https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-2439 affected

Comment: I have raised this as Railo bug https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-2698 - this should probably be closed off as there doesn't seem to be any workaround required at my end, really it should be fixed within Railo

Comment: The issue raised in this question is instead a bug in Railo, and I have now been able to raise it as such.  There will be no useful answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following 2 methods are what I am using in place of ObjectSave and ObjectLoad until the Railo bug is corrected.  It seems to function up to a decent level of complexity.

```
// Replaces ObjectSave
private binary function serializeState(
    required struct inState
) {
    var strSerialized = serialize(arguments.inState);
    return strSerialized.GetBytes();
}

// Replaces ObjectLoad
private struct function deserializeState(
    required binary inState
) {
    var strSerialized = ToString(arguments.inState);
    var stcDeserialized = evaluate(strSerialized);
    return stcDeserialized;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at the stack trace. It answers all your questions.

```
java.io.UTFDataFormatException at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeUTF(ObjectOutputStream.java:2163):2163 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeUTF(ObjectOutputStream.java:2006):2006
```

A glance at the Javadoc shows that this exception is thrown by  `writeUTF()` if the data to be written is longer than 65535 bytes.

```
railo.runtime.ComponentImpl.writeExternal(ComponentImpl.java:1975):1975
```

This is the code that calls `writeUTF().` So it appears to be a bug in the `railo.runtime.ComponentImpl` class. It shouldn't be calling `writeUTF()` for such a long string.

Comment: I had seen about that 65k limit, however successfully managed to save a unit-test created object of over 100mb using ObjectSave, so size alone can't be the issue here.  It seems to be something about the use of ObjectSave within a `catch(){}` that causes this error, though as mentioned I'm still struggling to isolate a precise trigger for it + can't explain why it only seems to happen in a `catch`.  Thank you for the explanation there though, I'll look back at the railo source code + see if anything jumps out at me (though I've not touched Java as much as I should have!)

Comment: The 'railo' class concerned has a `writeExternal()` method that calls `writeUTF()` for Strings. It should call `writeObject().`

Comment: I see the lines you mean, thank you for this additional information - hopefully it will allow them to fix it swiftly once I'm able to provide reproduction steps!